# Does using a credit card's rental car protection in case of a damage with car rental result in increase of some premium or extra fees?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, rent, car-insurance

Many credit cards in the United States offer some kind of [rental car protection](https://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/car-rental-insurance-coverage-1273.php) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222015750/https://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/car-rental-insurance-coverage-1273.php)). In case of a damage  to the rented car, does using the credit card's rental car protection in case of a damage with car rental result in increase of some premium (as a typical car insurance contract would) or extra fees for the customer?

Answer (score 3):

That would depend on your specific contract - they are not all created equal.
Typically, no negative consequences should arise; worst case, if you use it multiple times, they smell fraud, and will check each case *very* thoroughly, and finally terminate your credit card.

[I have used it once, and it was a smooth ride, with no consequences]

Comment: As an example of differing contracts, American Express offers some rental insurance at no cost, but account holders have the option of purchasing additional "[premium](https://feeservices.americanexpress.com/premium/car-rental-insurance-coverage/home.do)" insurance at a fixed price per rental contract purchase - if enrolled it gets automatically billed when a car rental purchase is recognized in the account holder's transactions.